# can nginx block incoming headers as reverse proxy / uwsgi client

Tags: nginx, uwsgi, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am using nginx and would like to block certain incoming headers, such, that

- uwsgi never receives these headers
- a server / service that I proxy to will not receive them

How can I achieve this

Answer (score 0):

You can hide a request header with [proxy_set_header](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header) directive.

```
proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
```

Comment: Thanks. will this also work for uwsgi?